# How work with the pivot model in has many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pivot-table, has-many

Im confuse with has_many through models in rails 4, I have 3 models

**profile:**

```
has_many :profile_services 
has_many :services, through: :profile_services
```

**service:**

```
has_many :profile_services
has_many :profiles, through: :profile_services
```

**profile_service:**

```
belongs_to :profile
belongs_to :service
```

so in my service model have name and description, and in my profile_service have price because I need when the user create the profile automatically have 3 services and he just can give a price for your services

And this logic is complicated for me because I think I don't need service controller because I will create this info with a seed just need create a controller for profile_service because the user add a price for these services but I don't know how to create these 3 services automatically when create the profile...

any suggestions? just to clear my mind

thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You may use ActiveRecord [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to perform any required initialization operations in your models.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :setup_services

  def setup_services
    # create appropriate services for the profile
  end
end
```

Comment: ohh thanks @Dimitris, so, inside method will be something like:

`@profile_services = @profile.build_services` ? 

and work in the services view? with something like: 

`<%= f.simple_fields_for :profile_services do |builder| %>`